# Why cannot I show Interstitial ads?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried many things but I could not make interstitial ads display in Unity. I want to show interstitial ads after users select a wrong answer and before the score page ("Notice" scene) displays. Here is my code, I just copied relevant parts:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Xml;
 using System.Collections;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Xml.Serialization;
 using System.IO;
 using GoogleMobileAds;
 using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

 public class responder : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private InterstitialAd interstitial;

     private int gecis;

     public Text questionsorular;
     public Text responseA;
     public Text responseB;
     public Text responseC;
     public Text responseD;
     public Text infoResponses;
     public Text infoResponses1;
     public Text example;
     public Text dogrusayisi;

     private float corrects;
     private float questoesquestions;
     private float media;
     private int Notice;
 }

 void Start()
 {
     RequestInterstitial();
 }

 public void response(string alternative)
 {

     RequestInterstitial();

     if (alternative == "A")
     {
         if (responseA.text == infoResponses.text)
         {
             corrects += 1;
             nextQuestion();
         }
         else
         {
             Invoke("wrong", 1);
         }
     }

     else if (alternative == "B")
     {
         if (responseB.text == infoResponses.text)
         {
             corrects += 1;
             nextQuestion();
         }
         else
         {
             Invoke("wrong", 1);
         }
     }

     else if (alternative == "C")
     {
         if (responseC.text == infoResponses.text)
         {
             corrects += 1;
             nextQuestion();
         }
         else
         {
             Invoke("wrong", 1);
         }
     }

     else if (alternative == "D")
     {
         if (responseD.text == infoResponses.text)
         {
             corrects += 1;
             nextQuestion();
         }
         else
         {
             Invoke("wrong", 1);
         }
     }
 }

 void wrong()
 {
     ShowInterstitial();
     Application.LoadLevel("Notice");
 }

 private void RequestInterstitial()
 {
 #if UNITY_EDITOR
     string adUnitId = "unused";
 #elif UNITY_ANDROID
             string adUnitId = "MY ADS ID";
 #elif UNITY_IPHONE
             string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
 #else
             string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
 #endif

     // Create an interstitial.
     interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
     // Load an interstitial ad.
     interstitial.LoadAd(createAdRequest());
 }

 private AdRequest createAdRequest()
 {
     return new AdRequest.Builder()
             .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
             .AddTestDevice("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF")
             .AddKeyword("game")
             .SetGender(Gender.Male)
             .SetBirthday(new DateTime(1985, 1, 1))
             .TagForChildDirectedTreatment(false)
             .AddExtra("color_bg", "9B30FF")
             .Build();
 }

 private void ShowInterstitial()
 {
     if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
     {
         interstitial.Show();
     }
 }
```

Following code works perfectly for banner ads when I attached it to camera:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

 public class Ads : MonoBehaviour
 {
     void Start()
     {
         BannerView adsObject = new BannerView(
                 "MY ADS ID", AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);
         AdRequest getAds = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
         adsObject.LoadAd(getAds);
         }
 }
```

Comment: In the first code sample you call many functions between Builder() and Build(), while you don't do it in the second example. Are you completely sure those functions aren't provoking the error? Try to change "createAdRequest" to AdRequest.Builder().Build();

Comment: @cFrozenDeath thank you for your response. I also tried AdRequest.Builder().Build(); you can see my code by clicking on following link: http://codeshare.io/7ddTa However, it does not work.

Comment: I am using Google Mobile Ad Unity Plugin that is supported by Google. The one who coded this plugin also shared sample code that can be found from here: http://codeshare.io/Tftar When I attached this code to camera, some buttons become active: http://i.imgur.com/TtMYMhR.png but when I click on Request Interstitial button and then, click on Show Interstitial button, it also does not work at the first time. I mean sometimes I need to click on Show Interstitial button more than once to show interstitial ads. That's why I am starting to believe something is wrong in that plugin or Admob system. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it!

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Xml;
 using System.Collections;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Xml.Serialization;
 using System.IO;
 using GoogleMobileAds;
 using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

 public class responder : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private InterstitialAd adObject;

     private int gecis;

     public Text questionsorular;
     public Text responseA;
     public Text responseB;
     public Text responseC;
     public Text responseD;
     public Text infoResponses;
     public Text infoResponses1;
     public Text example;
     public Text dogrusayisi;

     private float corrects;
     private float questoesquestions;
     private float media;
     private int Notice;
 }

 void Start()
 {
     GetNewAds( null, null );
 }

 public void response(string alternative)
 {


     if (alternative == "A")
     {
         if (responseA.text == infoResponses.text)
         {
             corrects += 1;
             nextQuestion();
         }
         else
         {
             Invoke("wrong", 1);
         }
     }

     else if (alternative == "B")
     {
         if (responseB.text == infoResponses.text)
         {
             corrects += 1;
             nextQuestion();
         }
         else
         {
             Invoke("wrong", 1);
         }
     }

     else if (alternative == "C")
     {
         if (responseC.text == infoResponses.text)
         {
             corrects += 1;
             nextQuestion();
         }
         else
         {
             Invoke("wrong", 1);
         }
     }

     else if (alternative == "D")
     {
         if (responseD.text == infoResponses.text)
         {
             corrects += 1;
             nextQuestion();
         }
         else
         {
             Invoke("wrong", 1);
         }
     }
 }

 void wrong()
 {
     StartCoroutine(ShowAds());
     Application.LoadLevel("Notice");
 }

IEnumerator ShowAds()
    {
        while( !adObject.IsLoaded() )
            yield return null;

        adObject.Show();
    }

    public void GetNewAds( object sender, EventArgs args )
    {
        if( adObject != null )
            adObject.Destroy();

        adObject = new InterstitialAd( "AD UNIT ID" );
        adObject.AdClosed += GetNewAds;

        AdRequest GetAds = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        adObject.LoadAd( GetAds );
    }
}
```